# Set Timeout THttpRio object for Mobile Project

Tags: android, iphone, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

I really need your help. I have an object THttpRio. The user with the form choose the Ip and the port of the server. It works fine but when i try to go on fake ip... i have something like 3min before have an error...

I tried to change that :

```
fHttpRIO.HTTPWebNode.ConnectTimeout := 1000;
fHttpRIO.HTTPWebNode.SendTimeout := 1000;
fHttpRIO.HTTPWebNode.ReceiveTimeout := 1000;
```

but don't work in this case ....

When i seach on internet i only find like this :

```
procedure TForm2.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(
      const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
    var TimeOut : integer;
    begin
        TimeOut := 2000;
        InternetSetOption(Data, 
             INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, 
             Pointer(@TimeOut), SizeOf(TimeOut));
    end;
```

But "InternetSetOption" is windows API, not android or Iphone. How can i define a timeout for my object please ?

My code is :

```
function TWebServiceCommunication.InitWebService(aIp :String; aPort :Integer; aIpConfigServer :String; aPortConfigServer :Integer) :Integer;
var
  wAddr : string;
begin
  try
    if aIpConfigServer = ''   then aIpConfigServer := aIp;
    if aPortConfigServer = 0  then aPortConfigServer := aPort;


    wAddr := Format( 'http://%s:%d/wsdl/IMDWWebService',[aIpConfigServer, aPortConfigServer]);
    fHttpRIO.WSDLLocation := wAddr;

    fHttpRIO.URL := Format( 'http://%s:%d/soap/IMDWWebService',[AIp,APort]);
    fHttpRIO.Port := 'IMDWWebServicePort';
    fHttpRIO.Service := 'IMDWWebServiceservice';
      fHttpRIO.HTTPWebNode.ConnectTimeout := 10000;
      fHttpRIO.HTTPWebNode.SendTimeout := 100000;
      fHttpRIO.HTTPWebNode.ReceiveTimeout := 100000;

    fHttpRIO.Converter := TOPToSoapDomConvert.Create(fHttpRIO.Converter.Owner);
    fHttpRIO.Converter.Encoding := 'UTF-8';


   // fHttpRIO.Converter.Options := [soSendMultiRefObj, soDocument, soTryAllSchema];

    fWSInterface := GetIMDWWebService(True, wAddr, fHttpRIO);

    fToken := fWSInterface.SimpleLogin(_SYSTEM_WS_LOGIN, _SYSTEM_WS_PASSWORD);
    Result := fToken;
    if fToken = -1 then
      raise Exception.Create('[TWebServiceCommunication.InitWebService] : Invalide token');

  Except
    On E:Exception do
      raise Exception.Create('[TWebServiceCommunication.InitWebService] : Connection Error '+ e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Thanks you very much for try to help me, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: No Idea for help me ? :(